# Google Chrome не видит профили

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

Запускал selenium python и пропали профили в браузере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако в папке \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data профили сохранились:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему они удалились из браузера?
Как можно сделать чтобы браузер их снова обнаружил?

Answer (score 1):

Хром разрешает запуск селениум только с новым чистым профилем.

Можно попробовать скопировать ваш профиль в другое место и в селениум указать путь к этому профилю.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете указать путь к `User Data` и желаемый профайл через параметры запуска:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 2")

service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```